# How to print data.frame values line by line

Tags: r

I want to convert data.frame to this format:

```
(col1row1Value, col2row1Value, ... colNrow1Value),
(col1row2Value, col2row2Value, ... colNrow2Value),
...
(col1rowNValue, col2rowNValue, ... colNrowNValue)
```

this is my dirty solution:

```
convert <- function(df) {
  df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors = F)

  result <- ""
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    x <- paste(df[i, ], collapse = ", ")
    result <- paste0(result, "(", x, "),\n" )
  }
  result <- substr(result, 1, nchar(result) - 1)
  result
}
```

test:

```
cat(convert(iris[1:5,]))
```

any ideas how to imporove it?

Comment: run this code then ya will see... I need to convert data.frame to the first format as character)

Comment: Does it have to be automated? Can you write to file?

Comment: automatic and can be written to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
iris$new<- apply(iris, 1,paste0, collapse = ",")
print(apply(iris[,6, drop= F], 2, function(f) paste0("(", f, ")", collapse= ",")))
```

Comment: you can simplify this into : `paste0("(",apply(head(iris),1,paste ,collapse=", "),")",collapse=",\n")`

Comment: True. thank you @Moody_Mudskipper
so if as requested it should be separated by comma rather than '/n'

Comment: Rifa1234 and Moody_Mudskipper can I use yours code in my commercial app?

Comment: sure, and we would have no right to stop you if we wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with the tidyverse :

```
convert <- function (df) 
  df %>% mutate_if(Negate(is.character),as.character) %>%
    mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
    gather(k,v,-id) %>%
    group_by(id) %>% summarise(z=paste0("(",paste(v,collapse=", "),")")) %>%
    pull(z) %>% paste(collapse=",\n")

cat(convert(iris[1:5,]))
#(5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, setosa),
#(4.9, 3, 1.4, 0.2, setosa),
#(4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, setosa),
#(4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, setosa),
#(5, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, setosa)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it (you can wrap this in a function if you want).

```
itest <- iris[1:5,] %>%
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species))

ct <- 1:nrow(itest)

tbl <- tibble()

for (i in ct) {

  r <- itest[i,]
  newct <- 1:ncol(r)

  vals <- character()

  for (i in newct) {

    new_val <- r[,i]

    vals <- c(vals,new_val)
  }

  new_tbl <- tibble(stringrow = paste(vals,collapse=', '))

  tbl <- bind_rows(tbl,new_tbl)

}
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  stringrow                 
  <chr>                     
1 5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, setosa
2 4.9, 3, 1.4, 0.2, setosa  
3 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, setosa
4 4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, setosa
5 5, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, setosa
```